# High-dpi screen having troubles with exporting DensityPlot as PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format, save

I recently upgraded my laptop to one with a higher dpi screen (72->96), and it has caused a world of problems with various applications, specifically Mathematica.

I run Ubuntu 18.04, and previous to upgrading laptops everything worked perfectly fine.

However now when I try to export DensityPlot PDFs, for example plots that looks like this in my notebook:

[image]

turns out terribly when exported (via right-click->Save image):

[image]

All of the text, and data points get cut off, and it looks terrible! Alternatively, if I use the Export["...",plot"] command, I get *massive* files that take my pdf reader a few minutes to load, and leaves Latex crashing, however, the text looks fine.
I've never had this issue until now with my new computer, and It happens on both Mathematica 11.1 and 12.0!

Does anyone have any experience or suggestions with this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Zack

Comment: The result of `Export` should not depend on the screen resolution. If it does, that would be a bug. I suggest you contact Wolfram Support about this.